# SSRS Report - IIF statement Question

Tags: sql, if-statement, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

Doing an expression I get an error, can someone show me the correct syntax here?

```
=IIf(Fields!t_cpcp.Value ="310", "Purchased Material & Raw Material", Nothing)
=IIf(Fields!t_cpcp.Value ="320", "Manufacturing Direct Labor", Nothing)
=IIf(Fields!t_cpcp.Value ="325", "Subcontract Cost", Nothing)
=IIf(Fields!t_cpcp.Value ="330", "Engineering Direct Labor", Nothing)
=IIf(Fields!t_cpcp.Value ="340", "Manufacturing Labor O/H", Nothing)
=IIf(Fields!t_cpcp.Value ="345", "Engineering Labor O/H", Nothing)
=IIf(Fields!t_cpcp.Value ="350", "Material O/H", Nothing)
=IIf(Fields!t_cpcp.Value ="355", "Labor O/H Surcharge", Nothing)
=IIf(Fields!t_cpcp.Value ="360", "Subcontract Material Burden", Nothing)
=IIf(Fields!t_cpcp.Value ="MFD", "Manufactured Items", Nothing)
```

Comment: Any chance of telling us what the error is?

Comment: Is it one expression or multiple expressions?, cause you are showing a lot more than one expression

Comment: Well I have one column that returns a value and based on that value I want the expression column to show one of the values in the query above. So its one.

Comment: The error i get is BC30205, End of statement expected. BUt I think its wrong overall, not sure.

Comment: You need either a switch statement or nested iif statements.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want this to all be in one expression, you may want to use the SWITCH statement:

```
=Switch(<condition>, <return value if true>, <next condition>, <return value if true>, ...)
```

The switch statement will return the value for the first condition that is true.Using your example, you could try:

```
=Switch(Fields!t_cpcp.Value ="310", "Purchased Material & Raw Material",
        Fields!t_cpcp.Value ="320", "Manufacturing Direct Labor",
        Fields!t_cpcp.Value ="325", "Subcontract Cost",
        ...rest of them go here...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another less elegant way would be to nest your IIF Statements

```
=IIf(Fields!t_cpcp.Value ="310", "Purchased Material & Raw Material",IIf(Fields!t_cpcp.Value ="320", "Manufacturing Direct Labor",IIf(Fields!t_cpcp.Value ="325", "Subcontract Cost",IIf(Fields!t_cpcp.Value ="330", "Engineering Direct Labor",IIf(Fields!t_cpcp.Value ="340", "Manufacturing Labor O/H",IIf(Fields!t_cpcp.Value ="345", "Engineering Labor O/H",IIf(Fields!t_cpcp.Value ="350", "Material O/H",IIf(Fields!t_cpcp.Value ="355", "Labor O/H Surcharge",IIf(Fields!t_cpcp.Value ="360", "Subcontract Material Burden",IIf(Fields!t_cpcp.Value ="MFD", "Manufactured Items", Nothing))))))))))
```

You could also do your logic in the query:

```
CASE t_cpcp WHEN '310' THEN 'Purchased Material & Raw Material'
            WHEN '320' THEN 'Manufacturing Direct Labor'
            WHEN  ...    THEN ....
            ELSE ''
END as t_cpcp_DESC
```